# Scala Import Function in Scope Multiple Times

Tags: python, scala

I am learning Scala and run into this problem using Scala REPL. I am playing with `immutable.Map` and `mutable.Map`,

```
  Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_60).
  scala> Map
  res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map.type = scala.collection.immutable.Map$@2e32ccc5

  scala> var mymap = Map[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two", 3->"three")
  mymap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two, 3 -> three)

  scala> import scala.collection.mutable.Map
  import scala.collection.mutable.Map

  scala> var mymap1 = Map[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two", 3->"three")
  mymap1: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(2 -> two, 1 -> one, 3 -> three)

  scala> import scala.collection.immutable.Map
  import scala.collection.immutable.Map

  scala> var mymap2 = Map[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two", 3->"three")
  <console>:9: error: reference to Map is ambiguous;
  it is imported twice in the same scope by
  import scala.collection.immutable.Map
  and import scala.collection.mutable.Map
   var mymap2 = Map[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two", 3->"three")
                ^
  scala>
```

Does that mean I can only import the same function name once? I have a Python background and seems like I can import as many times as I want. Is that the case? If so, what is the design philosophy here:

```
  # I created two files in the working directory module1 and module2 and they
  # both have a function called myfunc() to its corresponding module name. 
  Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
  [GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> from module1 import myfunc
  >>> print myfunc()
  module1
  >>> from module2 import myfunc
  >>> print myfunc()
  module2
  >>> from module1 import myfunc
  >>> print myfunc()
  module1
  >>>
```

Comment: Rules for name binding are surprisingly not dead simple: http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/02-identifiers-names-and-scopes.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import one of the types with a name change, which can often be a useful signal of what type of entity you are dealing with anyway. Examples:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MMap} // or MutableMap, or whatever label you find useful
scala> import java.util.{Map => JMap} // or JavaMap, or whatever
```

Then use the imported types via the new (local) name:

```
scala> var mymap1 = MMap[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two", 3->"three")
mymap1: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(2 -> two, 1 -> one, 3 -> three)

scala> import scala.collection.immutable.Map
import scala.collection.immutable.Map

scala> var mymap2 = Map[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two", 3->"three")
mymap2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> one, 2 -> two, 3 -> three)
```

Comment: You have the difference between mutable and immutable implementations of some types within certain Scala libraries, (Map is an example)...which I don't *think* you have within Python so much (although I've never really looked at Python).  This is the reason why you ended up with an ambiguous reference to the same type.   You could also fully-qualify the types when you create them so something like:  val myMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map or val myMap = scala.collection.immutable.Map.   Generally, the use of the immutable variant is more idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

Scala's REPL is probably keeping the same behavior scala has when compiling regular code (not from repl):

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala -nc -save "$0" "$@"
!#

object Hello {
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit = {
    println("Hello, Scala !! ")
    var mymap = Map[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two", 3->"three")

    import scala.collection.mutable.Map

    var mymap1 = Map[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two", 3->"three")

    import scala.collection.immutable.Map

    var mymap2 = Map[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two", 3->"three")
  }
}
```

Returns a compilation error:

```
error: reference to Map is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import scala.collection.immutable.Map
and import scala.collection.mutable.Map
    var mymap2 = Map[Int, String](1->"one", 2->"two", 3->"three")
```

In python, this doesn't give any errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())

from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())

from datetime import datetime
print(datetime.now())
```

Prints

```
2015-10-31 01:47:25.492501
2015-10-31 01:47:25.492589
2015-10-31 01:47:25.492609
```

If you really want to this in scala's REPL you can do what Shadowlands suggested.

Or you can use scala's `ipython`-like alternative:

[Ammonite - A Modernized Scala REPL](http://lihaoyi.github.io/Ammonite/#Ammonite-REPL)

I test locally with my ammonite, repeated your steps and the problem didn't happen. Probably ammonite does something smarter to avoid import conflicts in REPL (but the would still give you a compilation error in regular scala code)

Comment: Warning: ammonite is a little bit heavier and slower than scala's repl. :P

Comment: There's a difference between importing different symbols and importing the same symbol twice.